# CakePHP 4 Saving Data Twice

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

CakePHP is somehow saving the same data twice. For some reason I want to implement this add method such that $dummy is saved right away as someone goes directly to `domain.com/recordings/add`

It looks pretty straight forward and I've been scratching my head. I've checked for validation errors; I've tried disabling validation; I've tried using `patchEntity()` instead.

Though, one strange thing is that, if you go to `domain.com/recordings/add` by hitting the `add recording` button in `domain.com/recordings/index` (instead of typing the url out on the browser), the data is saved just once.

Controller:

```
public function add()
{
    $dummy = [
        "user_id" => 1,
        "title" => "tgfbthgdthb",
        "body" => "rgcvfghfhdxcgb",
        "published" => 0,
    ];

    $recording = $this->Recordings->newEntity($dummy);

    $this->Recordings->save($recording);
}
```

Model/table:

```
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('recordings');
    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Words', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recording_id',
    ]);
}
```

Model/entity:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'user_id' => true,
    'title' => true,
    // 'slug' => true,
    'body' => true,
    'published' => true,
    'created' => true,
    'modified' => true,
    'user' => true,
    'words' => true,
];
```

The view:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \App\View\AppView $this
 * @var \App\Model\Entity\Recording $recording
 */
?>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="column">
        <div class="side-nav">
            <h4 class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></h4>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('List Recordings'), ['action' => 'index'], ['class' => 'side-nav-item']) ?>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="column-responsive column-80">
        <div class="recordings form content">
            <?= $this->Form->create($recording) ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><?= __('Add Recording') ?></legend>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
                    echo $this->Form->control('title');
                    echo $this->Form->control('body');
                    echo $this->Form->control('published');
                ?>
            </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to accommodate to people's lazyness, do not allow them to save data by simply visiting a URL, ie via a `GET` request, that's just going to cause trouble, and on top of that it's bad application design.

Implement at least a proper safeguard that only saves data for `POST` requests.

Browsers may issue multiple requests in various scenarios, from preflight `OPTIONS` requests to weird quirks, like for example Firefox aborting the request if doesn't find any encoding information in the first x bytes of response data, and then issuing a new request that assumes a specific encoding for the response.

```php
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // save data here
    }
}
```